# Specify object implements protocol and inherits from class

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

Suppose I have a protocol

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Protocol

class Supports_connect(Protocol):
    address: int

    @abstractmethod
    def connect(self) -> None:
        ...
```

And some unrelated to this protocol class

```
class Camera:
    pass  #some implementation
```

And in function, I want to accept objects implementing the `Supports_connect` protocol and inherited from `Camera` class. (i.e. want to accept only cameras that support connect)

```
def connect_cameras(camera: IsCamera_and_supports_connect):
   camera.connect()
```

How do I type it? What `IsCamera_and_supports_connect` should be?

Comment: intersection types. [not yet supported](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213)

Answer (score 0):

As said by [@joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5986907/joel), an Intersection would be great.

But I found a workaround: we can inherit from class that implements protocol:

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Protocol


class Supports_connect(Protocol):
    address: int

    @abstractmethod
    def connect(self) -> None:
        ...


class connect_implementation(Supports_connect):
    def __init__(self, address: int) -> None:
        self.address = address

    def connect(self) -> None:
        print("Connected")


class Camera:
    pass  # some implementation


class IsCamera_and_supports_connect(Camera, connect_implementation):
    ...
```

And here it is